# What is the correct way to install Adwaita theme on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, gtk3, gtk-2

I want to have Adwaita theme on Ubuntu 12.04. On my previous installation I had it in unity right after installing gnome3 shell. Gtk2 apps didn't have tabs like what it would be expected on Gtk3 and they were ugly. For example Gedit had Adwaita tabs, but Firefox settings page didn't.

Now, I have a new installation of Ubuntu 12.04, and I want to have Adwaita theme. What is the correct way to install Adwaita theme so that those problems won't occur?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this theme you looking for? http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-j3sNph9aQr8/USn31_eq_JI/AAAAAAAACU0/MBFid7TPMYk/s400/adwaita-elements-theme.jpg

Comment: Not really, but it is really alike.look here http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/